# Using a Certificate Revocation List on a Closed Network (no Internet Access)

Tags: java, applet, certificate, certificate-revocation

Our web application uses applets for many of its functions, and we are currently signing those applets with a CA issued certificate.  The CA provides a Revocation List.  Several of the sites using our application are closed networks, with no access to the internet, and we are trying to figure out how to get the CRL onto those networks, and checked when a certificate is used.

From what I have found so far, we have the option to fully disable CRL checking, in the Java options, but I’m not sure this is the best option.  Would we get security warnings when launching applets if we did this?  Additionally, it may become a requirement that we check the CRL.

So I think the real questions here are:

1: How do we point Java at the CRL located on our closed network?

2: Can we place it on the server, or does it have to be deployed to each machine?

3: If there are settings that have to be in place on each machine, is there a good option for pushing them out from the server?

Comment: If the sites are closed, why are you concerned about a CRL? Presumably, if you know the (local) server involved is compromised, you'll fix it.

Comment: That's a really good question that I'm trying to get answered.  But for the moment I'm stuck with the inevitability of the CRL check being required by those above me.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I'm facing the same problem in the days...
Disabling checking the CRL is not an option in my case, because of security.
The very best option is ensuring Internet access up to the CRL and the OCSP responder.
I would also cite OCSP stapling here, but I think this is not an option in a code-signing scenario, since OCSP stapling only work in presence of a TLS handshake.

Another option could be to maintain up-to-date local copies of the needed CRLs and use fake DNS records. That way a client trying to access the CRL will be redirected to a local server, with the copy of the original CRL.
Maybe you'll have to create a web server and have a cron script fetching a copy of every CRL on a daily basis. The fake DNS record should then point to this server.